# Extending the RenderField.GetFieldValue processor - not all items associated with the page are processed

Tags: sitecore, sitecore8

I have a rich text field that has certain tokens (`{{alt}}` and `{{title}}`) for embedded images in the HTML. I extended the `Sitecore.Pipelines.RenderField.GetFieldValue` processor so that when a page is rendered on the front end, the processor will replace those tokens with the alt and title field values from the media item. Unfortunately my custom processor only processes a certain set of items (specifically WFFM fields), it does not process my `Body` field which has the tokens, even though I know the page I am browsing is rendering that field (the code run on the layout is `@Html.Sitecore().Field("Body")` which means it should get processed by the pipeline, correct?)

I also tried the `GetTextFieldValue` and `GetMemoFieldValue` processors but the same items were processed. Looking for some guidance as to specifically which fields are supposed to get processed by this pipeline.

Here is my Process() function:

```
    public void Process(RenderFieldArgs args)
    {
        Assert.ArgumentNotNull(args, "args");
        Assert.ArgumentNotNull(args.Item, "args.Item");
        Assert.ArgumentNotNull(args.GetField(), "args.GetField()");

        if (args.Item.Database == Database.GetDatabase("web"))
        {
            if (args.GetField().Value.Contains("{{alt}}"))
            {
                args.GetField().Value = ReplaceAltToken(args.GetField().Value);
            }

            if (args.GetField().Value.Contains("{{title}}"))
            {
                args.GetField().Value = ReplaceTitleToken(args.GetField().Value);
            }

            if (args.GetField().Name == "Body")
            {
                // Since we're rendering the body field differently we need to expand dynamic links
                args.Item.Editing.BeginEdit();
                args.GetField().Value = Sitecore.Links.LinkManager.ExpandDynamicLinks(args.GetField().Value);
                args.Item.Editing.EndEdit();
            }
        }
    }
```

My config include file:

```
<configuration xmlns:patch="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/">
<sitecore>
    <pipelines>
        <renderField>
            <processor
                type="[Redacted].Processor.RenderField.GetFieldValueExtended, [Redacted].Processor"
                patch:after="processor[@type='Sitecore.Pipelines.RenderField.GetFieldValue, Sitecore.Kernel']" />
        </renderField>
    </pipelines>
</sitecore>
```

Comment: Do you have caching enabled on the renderings? Are you sure the pipelines are not hit being you are serving up a cached version of the components? Also, you have a check for the `web` database, are you checking this on CD server or CM server?

Comment: Ok, cacheable was set on all renderings. I unchecked it on all and published all renderings - which I'm not sure was actually required. Anything else I would need to do? So far I am still not getting any more items. I am debugging locally so CD + CM on same server.

Comment: Ok so it looks like I did not push the updated view to the web root of the site from my solution, so @Html.Sitecore().Field("Body") was not called. It's calling it now, which I assume will run the render field pipeline again, BUT I'm getting this error when the .Field() call is run: `Attempt to retrieve context object of type 'Sitecore.Mvc.Presentation.PageContext' from empty stack.`

Comment: I don't know I'm afraid. Maybe post up details of your View (and any models you are using). I almost exclusively use Glass Mapper with Sitecore.

Comment: Just resolved it - posting an answer shortly which will explain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There were multiple steps to resolving this issue. Unchecking `Cacheable` on all renderings was an important first step. The rest of the issues I encountered were most likely specific to my solution (not well designed and will be refactored soon).

My local site did not have the most up to date files. When I updated the files, I still ran into the `Attempt to retrieve context object of type 'Sitecore.Mvc.Presentation.PageContext' from empty stack` error, which I was able to workaround by calling `Sitecore.Web.UI.WebControls.FieldRenderer.Render(item, "Body")` in a simple GetBody() function in the model, instead of `Html.Sitecore().Field("Body")`. Then in the view I simply put `@Html.Raw(Model.Body)`.

I think the `.Field()` helper did not work because the item associated with the field requested was unknown, so yet another workaround is using `Html.Sitecore().Field("Body", item)` which specifies the item directly in the parameters.